# Part 2 of blackjack game

Tags: python

I posted [the first part of this game](/q/237148) earlier, and now I finished the second part.

From the first part we just had to have a random value to get the cards, and the bet always stayed at $25. For the second part the user could choose their bet, enter 0 to quit the game completely, and just hit enter to default to 25 on their first round, or can stay with their bet from the previous round.

My code is super messy and very long. I know it can be cleared up and made much shorter as I've seen people with around 70 lines of code.

```
import random

def main():
  restart = True

  bank_balance = 1000
  player_name = input("Please enter your name: ")
  #Default bet
  user_bet=25
  while restart:

    print (f"Welcome {player_name}, your bank balance is ${bank_balance} ")

    bet = input_bet(user_bet, bank_balance)

    #Returned value from input_bet to stop the program
    if (bet == -10):
      break

    win_lose = play_hand(player_name, bet)
    bank_balance+=win_lose

    print(f'Your bank balance: ${bank_balance}')

def input_bet(bet, money):
  correct = False
  while not correct:
    if (money <=0):
      print('You ran out of money')
      return -10

    str_bet=input("Bet? (0 to quit, press 'Enter' to stay at $25) ")

    if (str_bet == ''):
      print(f'Staying at ${bet}')
      return bet

    try:
      enough_money = False
      while not enough_money:
        bet=int(str_bet)
        if (bet > money):
          print('not enough money')
          str_bet=input("Bet? (0 to quit, press 'Enter' to stay at $25) ")
          bet=int(str_bet)
        if (bet < 0):
          print('Enter a number greater than 0')
          str_bet=input("Bet? (0 to quit, press 'Enter' to stay at $25) ")
          bet=int(str_bet)
        elif (bet == 0):
          return 0
        elif (bet <= money):
          print(f'Betting ${bet}')
          enough_money=True
          return bet

      correct = True

    except ValueError:
      print('Please enter a whole number')

def play_hand(name, bet):
  player= []
  dealer= []

  play_again = True

  dealer.append(random.randint(1, 11))

  player.extend([random.randint(1, 11), random.randint(1, 11)])

  print ('The dealer received card of value', *dealer)
  print(name, 'received cards of value', player[0], 'and', player[-1])
  print(f'Dealer total is {sum(dealer)}')
  print(f"{name}'s total is {sum(player)}", '\n')

  stay = False
  bust = False

  while (sum(player) <= 21 and stay == False and play_again == True):
    hors= input(f"Type 'h' to hit and 's' to stay ")
    if (hors == 'h'):
      new_card= random.randint(1, 11)
      player.append(new_card)
      print(f'{name} pulled a {new_card}')

      print(f'Dealer total is {sum(dealer)}')
      print(f"{name}'s cards are", *player)
      print(f"{name}'s total is {sum(player)}", '\n') 

    elif (hors == 's'):
      stay=True
      print('stay')

  if (sum(player) > 21 ):
    bust = True
    print('You busted!')
    return -bet

  while (stay == True and sum(dealer) < 17 and bust == False and play_again == True):
    dealer.append(random.randint(1, 11))
    print('The dealers cards are', *dealer)
    print('The dealers total is', sum(dealer), '\n')

  if (sum(dealer) <= 21 and sum(dealer) > sum(player)):
    print("The dealer wins!")
    return -bet

  elif (sum(player) <= 21 and sum(player) > sum(dealer)):
    print("You win!")
    return bet

  if (sum(dealer) > 21):
    print ('You win! The dealer busted!')
    return bet

  if (sum(dealer) == sum(player)):
    print('Its a Tie! ')
    return 0

main()
```

Answer (score 4):

## Indentation

You should indent **4** spaces. Here's the [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) guidelines on this.

## Equality

Instead of

> ```
> while (sum(player) <= 21 and stay == False and play_again == True):
> ```

do this

```
while(sum(player) <= 21 and not stay and play_again):
```

You don't need to `== True/False`, as those variables will equate to those boolean values already within the statement. This applies to other parts of your program as well.

## Operator spacing

There should be a space before and after every operator (`+` `-` `*` `/` `=`, etc.) in your program. This increases readability and makes your code look nicer.

## Unnecessary parentheses

You don't need parentheses around simple `if` statements, unless you're trying to group specific conditions with each other. But something like this:

> ```
> if (str_bet == ''):
> ```

should just be this

```
if str_bet == '':
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> if (sum(dealer) <= 21 and sum(dealer) > sum(player)):
>   print("The dealer wins!")
>   return -bet
> ```

A cool Python trick is that you can write:

```
if (sum(player) < sum(dealer) <= 21):
  print("The dealer wins!")
  return -bet
```

With the same meaning as above, but more natural.

---

> ```
> "Bet? (0 to quit, press 'Enter' to stay at $25) "
> ```

Is repeated 3 times, save it and reuse for easier changing of the message in the future:

```
ASK_BET = "Bet? (0 to quit, press 'Enter' to stay at $25) "
....

str_bet=input(ASK_BET)
```

---

> ```
>     if (bet == -10):
>       break
>
>     win_lose = play_hand(player_name, bet)
>     bank_balance+=win_lose
>
>     print(f'Your bank balance: ${bank_balance}')
>
> def input_bet(bet, money):
>   correct = False
>   while not correct:
>     if (money <=0):
>       print('You ran out of money')
>       return -10
> ```

you are using -10 as a special signal "flag" value, you should use `None` instead.

---

> ```
>   correct = False
>   while not correct:
> ```

You can just use `while True` and `break` or `return`.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing I noticed was that `while` loop in `play_hand()`. It has too many conditions. I'd just do `while True:` and then exit with a `break`.

You can do something similar in the other loop as well. This will make it so you don't have to repeat yourself so often and will significantly clean up your code.

Also there's a few other things you can do: You can simplify your dealer's code by just having the dealer get to 17 immediately instead of drawing one and then waiting until the player ended their turn.

You should move your over-21 check into the main `while` loop. And get rid of that `bust` variable, there's no need for it.

And there's no need for a `new_card` variable. Just check the end of the list of the player's cards.